# Why is using DMA on an STM32F4 a bad idea?

Tags: microcontroller

The bottom line is that somewhere the manufacturer writes that the implementation for these controllers is slightly incorrect - there may be failures, and the speed gain is insignificant. Can you tell me where I can read about this?

Comment: Why do you think it is a bad idea?

Comment: Post this manufacturers claims. IMO this is true in certain circumstances, depending on the application and not generally. From my point of view, I can see lot of users of this forum implementing DMA as first choice, even if their application doesn't need it, so this is the real trouble. The DMA isn't a magic wand, you should only use it where possible.

Comment: It is better you understand the need for DMA to be controlled with length of transfer known or controllable by stop/start . Every option has trade offs yet DMA is good for reducing memory and CPU overhead when longer than xx  bytes .  Search and you will find the answers

Comment: without posting the exact manufacturer claim, no reasonable answer can be given.

Answer (score 3):

The errata for that specific MCU, available on manufacturer website page for that specific MCU.